# Bash script select option based on value

Tags: bash, ssh, terminal

I have a command I would like to run in terminal.

eg.

samplecommand -s

Which provides an option later on:

1. Option 1
2. Option 2

with the input question
Please enter an index:

So I would need to input 2 into terminal.

However, the order of Option 1 and Option 2 change making it hard to hard code a specific index.

e.g. it could be:

1. Option 2
2. Option 1

Is there a way to use the context of options provided and make the script select only "Option 2".

Comment: Please have a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex).

Comment: [expect](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/) can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `se;ect`:

```
> select: select NAME [in WORDS ... ;] do COMMANDS; done
>     The WORDS are expanded, generating a list of words.  The
>     set of expanded words is printed on the standard error, each
>     preceded by a number.  If `in WORDS' is not present, `in "$@"'
>     is assumed.  The PS3 prompt is then displayed and a line read
>     from the standard input.  If the line consists of the number
>     corresponding to one of the displayed words, then NAME is set
>     to that word.  If the line is empty, WORDS and the prompt are
>     redisplayed.  If EOF is read, the command completes.  Any other
>     value read causes NAME to be set to null.  The line read is saved
>     in the variable REPLY.  COMMANDS are executed after each selection
>     until a break command is executed.
```